# Javascript array from all elements with a certain class name

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, functional-programming

I am trying to make an array from elements with a certain class in my web page. The array should get the videofile attribute value from all a tags with the class  videoLink.

The final values in the array should be.

```
 cycling_large, ocean_medium, winecountry_part1



 <a class="videoLink"  videofile="cycling_large"  ></a>
 <a class="videoLink" videofile="ocean_medium" ></a>
 <a class="videoLink" videofile="winecountry_part1" ></a>
```

I tried this but, does not work.

```
var values = $('.videoLink').map(function() { return this.attr('videofile'); }).get();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `videofile`? I think you mean `data-videofile`... `:P`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName("videoLink");
var values = [].map.call(links, function (el) {
  return el.getAttribute("videofile");
});
```

Because you don't jQuery for simple things.

Browser support:

- [ES5 shim](https://github.com/kriskowal/es5-shim)
- [DOM shim](https://github.com/Raynos/DOM-shim)

Comment: You will however, need to define the `array.map` prototype if you want this to support IE 8 and earlier, same with `document.getElementsByClassName`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: @wsanville yes. But there are shims for that.

Comment: No need for `slice` - just `[].map.call( links, function ( el ) { ...`

Answer (score 1):

Change `return this.attr('videofile');` to `return $(this).attr('videofile');`.
You need to enclose the `this` in `$()` so it becomes a jQuery object that you can then call `attr()` on.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/r9xJn/

Answer (score 0):

```
var result = $.map($('a.videoLink'), function(a) {
   return $(a).attr('videofile');
});
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/hY6zM/

Comment: If you look at the output in Firebug, or in the IE developer toolbar, or in Chrome, you'll see console.log will print `["cycling_large", "ocean_medium", "winecountry_part1"]`

Comment: How could I then store something like this in the array? video/'+ videofile +'.mp4

Comment: Change the return statement to:
`return 'video/' + $(a).attr('videofile') + '.mp4';`